# How to change AutoCompleteTextView handle background

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to customize the AutoCompleteTextView handle background.

The handle is the icon under the cursor when the text in the AutoCompleteTextView is selected.

As you can see in the image, when the text is selected the handle background (the square one behind of the green drop and under the cursor) has a color I don't know where it come from.

[image]

This is the approach I am doing:

*style.xml*

```
<style name="Autocomplete" parent="Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/text_black_color</item>
</style>
```

*View*

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:theme="@style/Autocomplete" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/spacing_sm"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:hint="@string/search"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorTextSearch"
        android:textSize="15.2sp"
        tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" />
```

I want to be able to let the handle background transpaarent. I have many hours trying to solve this.

I hope there is at least a workaround.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try changing the background color of autoComplete to transparent

Comment: @AnkushBist as you can see in the xml there is that property android:background="@android:color/transparent", there is no effect

Comment: you are mixing the background at style and at your AutoCompleteTextView. Please check your code

Comment: if I remove this line android:background="@android:color/transparent" and I keep the THEME it only change the style of the edittext of  the AutoCompleteTextView but the handle background stay the same

Comment: @AnkushBist On the other hand, if I delete the theme the dropdown background will be white

Comment: @AnkushBist thanks sir, you can see my answer and verify if it is correct. It solve my problem.

Answer (score 4):

1) To solve the problem of the handle background (the square one behind of the green drop and under the cursor) that is showing an odd background color, you have to define a style like this:

```
<style name="AutocompleteStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

1) To change the DropDownMenu background color of the AutoCompleteTextView you have to create a style as this:

```
<style name="DropDownMenuBackground">
    <item name="android:background">your_color</item>
</style>
```

and add this line in the AutocompleteStyle

```
<item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownMenuBackground</item>
```

3) Add this line in your AutoCompleteTextView to avoid its native style:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

How the complete style.xml looks now:

```
<style name="AutocompleteStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownMenuBackground</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownMenuBackground">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorSearch</item>
</style>
```

And obviously, don't forget to add your style to your autocompletetextview:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:theme="@style/AutocompleteStyle"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<style name="Autocomplete" parent="Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>



<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:theme="@style/Autocomplete" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/spacing_sm"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:hint="@string/search"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorTextSearch"
        android:textSize="15.2sp"
        tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" />
```

Comment: You can't use style as a background, this can't be the solution android:background="@styles/Autocomplete"

Comment: you are using black color in theme that is why this issue is coming

Comment: are you using custom cursor ?

Comment: No sir. The problem is if I don't use THEME. If I remove this line android:theme="@style/Autocomplete"  it works fine but the dropdownmenu background (AutoComplete opened) is white. I need this background to be black thats the reason I am using the theme.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133575/discussion-between-deneb-chorny-and-santosh-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

try this  property “android:textSelectHandle”

Answer (score 0):

**You can create your own 
style/theme for only this EditText and change the ColorAccent :**

```
<style name="EditTextColorCustom" parent="@style/AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```